# How can I load the website and then later add data to it in Asp.Net Core (C#) Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

so I'm trying to code a website that displays data from an API. I'm doing this in Asp.Net Core (Razor Pages). So I got my Data.cshtml which calls a function from Data.cshtml.cs, which returns the data. Until now everything runs synchronously. But I want it to load the website display a Text like "Please wait your website is getting loaded" and then as soon as the data is fully loaded I want it to be displayed. Is it possible and how would you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually in this scenarios you do Ajax calls to the API when the page loads and then render the section of the pages as the data from the APIs returns. The question is too broad. Can you narrow it down to what you have done in the page?

Comment: Well, I don't have to use Ajax because i can call the API from an integration into C# it's called Docuware. I then run a function which get's the data and returns HTML.

Comment: https://developer.docuware.com/dotNet/66b2ed1e-2aef-452a-97cd-5014bbf0242b.html Here is the link to the API.

Comment: C# runs on the server side. Code in any cshtml gets rendered on the server side. But you wanted to call the API after the page loads!

Comment: Do you have an example for that I can't find anything in Razor Pages?

Comment: Example of what?

Comment: Is there an event or a function that gets called when the webpage is loaded?

Comment: Page load happens on the client side. You will need javascript. Here is ajax method which will be executed after the page loads: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Thanks I found a way.

Answer (score 1):

So I found an answer in your page Script (cshtml) you just have to add this:

```
Response.OnCompleted(async () => {
       //Your Code
    });
```